# Can't install soil.h library

Tags: opengl, fedora, soil

I've made a simple opengl game which uses `soil.h` in ubuntu but in my college fedora is installed, how do install soil.h in fedora in my college pc?

I've already tried make **install method** in an earlier post and also tried  "`yum install libsoil.h-dev`" both didn't work, still `no SOIL/SOIL. H` file or directory found error.

Answer (score 0):

`SOIL.h` is a C header, i.e. a text file. And : A header is not a library.

The Fedora package name can be decided with `# yum provides */SOIL.h`

Install the package : `# yum install SOIL-devel`

Provides ...

```
/usr/include/SOIL
/usr/include/SOIL/SOIL.h
/usr/include/SOIL/image_DXT.h
/usr/include/SOIL/image_helper.h
/usr/include/SOIL/stb_image_aug.h
/usr/include/SOIL/stbi_DDS_aug.h
/usr/include/SOIL/stbi_DDS_aug_c.h
/usr/lib64/libSOIL.so
```

Comment: What does  #yum provides */SOIL. h do? Could  you please explain. Do I need to install package as root login?

Comment: »»What does #yum provides */SOIL. h do?««: As the command text says: Find the package name which provides */SOIL. h. .... Why are you asking about root login ? Please inform if you have the permission or have no root access. No permissions to install as root: Just unpack the package in your $HOME https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q3d9QqrRhEThYByPDgWEaoxHnqWFWqfE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So, I just need to rum the command "yum install SOIL-devel" with root access and my program should run fine with  - lSOIL flag

Comment: Exactly. ... If any issues, please add Fedora version to your question : **1**. `$ cat /etc/redhat-release`... **2**. `$ uname -m`

Comment: It's still not working, shows No package SOIL-devel available, Nothing to do. The fedora version is 12

Comment: No `SOIL-devel` for "Fedora old version year 2009" : SOIL-1.07 came with Fedora 19, not in earlier versions. Still the 2008 version `1.07` in in Fedora 28. Easy to build : BuildRequires = `libGL-devel`

Comment: Repeat : add Fedora version to your question → also the architecture, 32 or 64bits: `$ uname -m`